# Looking to solve the arbitrage search opportunity but have problems with the txt and matrix

Tags: python, bellman-ford

I want to solve the arbitrage problem using currencies.
Now I have a .txt with all the exchanges, but I want them to be like a matrix, where the element i,j is the rate of exchange from currency i to currency j.
BUT, I currently have a .txt like this:

**.txt like I have**

[image: .txt like I have]

How can I transform this .txt into a 2D array? I want to search for arbitrage opportunities with a minimal % of free-risk win. But first I need to model the problem, and then use Bellman-Ford for it.

Thank you so much!

PD: python user.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you want this in a 2-d array, I made my own txt file called **dic** (short for dictionary because I hate typing). It contains 2 strings and a numerical value:

```
a b 3
c d 6
```

The code I used to make the 2-d array goes something like this:

```
#Opens txt doc and creates the file reference(which I named file), "r" means read
file = open("dic","r")
#making a blank Array call Arr
Arr =[]
#making variable conveniently called line, which iterates for each line from the txt file
for line in file:
#variable x, the part which then seperates the string into it's 3 parts
    x = line.split()
#creates the list of each item in the line and adds them
    vals = [n for n in x]
    Arr.append(vals)
print(Arr)
file.close()
print (float(Arr[1][2])+3)
```

The key player in all of this is the split method, which allows you to separate the parts of text file.  Be warned: the numerical values would be treated as a string, so if you were to use them later on for math purposes you would have to parse them as a float, an example provided.

Comment: Hi and thanks. The problem is that the .txt is like:
a b 3
a c 4
a d 5
b a 6
b c 7
b d 8
...

so I was looking for a matrix that is more efficient to search the exchange rate from a currency i to all currencies in just the "i" line of the matrix.

Comment: Sorry, but I just want some quick clarification.  You want to find the best exchange rate for currency i to any other currency correct?  Or do you just want to list all the exchange rates from currency i?